# Unable to untar specific tar to its own DIR

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to untar a file which has a *tar.gz extension to its own directory.

```
tar -zxf /tmp/ranger/ranger-2.1.0-solr_audit_conf.tar.gz
```

If I do like above, it's untaring all files to its present working directory, but I want all those files go to its own DIR.

The following command extracts to a specific DIR:

```
tar -zxf /tmp/ranger/ranger-2.1.0-solr_audit_conf.tar.gz -C /tmp/ranger/ranger-2.1.0-solr_audit_conf
```

NOTE: If I try without -C for any other files, it is able to extract to its own DIR, which is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

`tar -x` will extract the contents of the `*.tar.*` file to the present working directory...  Period.  That being said, here's what that means, and how we can work around that to get the behaviour you want.

Usually, a directory is tarballed.  Meaning someone wrote:

```
tar -czf tarball.tar.gz somedirectory
```

In that case, if you `tar -x` it you'll get the contents extracted to `somedirectory`.  However that's only by convention.  It's very possible for someone to compress an archive with:

```
tar -czf tarball.tar.gz file1 file2 file3
```

In that case, when you `tar -x`, you'll get `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` in the current directory.

---

In this situation, if you want to keep the extracted files in an isolated directory, you should:

```
mkdir tarball && cd tarball && tar -xzf ../tarball.tar.gz
```

---

To understand if you should `tar -x` or `mkdir _ & cd _ & tar -x ../_`, you can use `tar --list -f tarball.tar.gz`.  This will list the contents of the tarball before you extract it so you can decide if you want to extract it to `pwd` as-is, or create a new directory and extract it from there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I did what you mentioned.